Horizontally match levels of Likert chart based on another bar plot in R
i have a data frame in r called df similar to these question found here:
set.seed(123)
likert_levels <- c(
  "1" = "Very  Dissatisfied",
  "2" = "Dissatisfied",
  "3" = "Neutral",
  "4" = "Satisfied",
  "5" = "Very  Satisfied")
df = data.frame(
  year = sample(c(2023, 2022, 2020, 2018), 50, replace = TRUE),
  A = sample(likert_levels, 50, replace = TRUE),
  B = sample(likert_levels, 50, replace = TRUE),
  C = sample(likert_levels, 50, replace = TRUE))%>%
  mutate(across(everything(),as.factor))%>%
  as_tibble()%>%
  mutate(across(-year, ~ factor(.x, levels = likert_levels)))
df


the likert chart i can do it like this :
mutate(df, id=row_number()) |>
  pivot_longer(-c(id, year), names_to="group") |>
  pivot_wider(names_from=year) |>
  gglikert(c(`2023`, `2022`, `2020`, `2018`), 
         facet_rows=vars(group))

but in this setup i want to sort the likert plot based on the descending sorting of the bar plot . I.e i want to sort first the bar plot in a descending order and then based on this sorting to be sorted accordingly the likert plot . How can i do it in R ?

Do you mean you want to sort by the bar plot on the right of the plot from the accepted answer in the other question you linked to?  ie you don't want the years in chronological order?  If that's the case, could you please at least make your question self contained and show what you have after incorporating what you learned from that other question?

@MichaelDewar The right bar  plot must show the occurrences of each year.The row count of each year if you want.And sorted in a descending order.The Left will be the Likert.But the years in the likert will be sorted based on the descending of the years in the bar plot.

Here is one potential approach:
library(tidyverse)
library(ggstats)
library(patchwork)

set.seed(123)
likert_levels <- c(
  "1" = "Very  Dissatisfied",
  "2" = "Dissatisfied",
  "3" = "Neutral",
  "4" = "Satisfied",
  "5" = "Very  Satisfied")
df = data.frame(
  year = sample(c(2023, 2022, 2020, 2018), 50, replace = TRUE),
  A = sample(likert_levels, 50, replace = TRUE),
  B = sample(likert_levels, 50, replace = TRUE),
  C = sample(likert_levels, 50, replace = TRUE))%>%
  mutate(across(everything(),as.factor))%>%
  as_tibble()%>%
  mutate(across(-year, ~ factor(.x, levels = likert_levels)))

# starting plot
likert <- df |>
  mutate(id = row_number()) |>
  pivot_longer(-c(id, year), names_to="group") |>
  pivot_wider(names_from=year) |>
  gglikert(c(`2023`, `2022`, `2020`, `2018`), 
           facet_rows=vars(group))

# get the order of years according to n
df2 <- df |>
  mutate(id = row_number()) |>
  pivot_longer(-c(id, year), names_to = "group") |>
  count(group, year) %>%
  arrange(n) %>%
  select(year) %>%
  distinct()

# change the order of years (.question) in the likert dataframe
likert$data <- likert$data |>
  mutate(.question = factor(.question, levels = df2$year))

# create the barplot
bar <- df |>
  mutate(id = row_number()) |>
  pivot_longer(-c(id, year), names_to = "group") |>
  count(group, year) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = n, y = fct_reorder(year, n))) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_label(aes(label = n),
             color = "white", hjust = 1,
             fill = NA, label.size = 0) +
  facet_wrap(~group, ncol = 1, strip.position = "right") +
  labs(y = NULL) +
  likert$theme

# plot them side by side
likert + bar + plot_layout(widths = c(0.8, 0.2), guides = "collect") &
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")


Created on 2024-12-13 with reprex v2.1.0
If this isn't your desired outcome, please edit your question and explain exactly what you want your final plot to look like.
